# how do I pass information from one class to another

Tags: java

I am creating a program which allows the user to input details of customers. When they have saved each customers record there is the choice to add additional information. I am having trouble getting the the name of the saved file in my append class. I need the filename so I  can then save the additional information to the same file already created for the customer. How do I pass the file name from one file to another.

```
File FName = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
      String name = FName.getName();

 public String getname() { return name; }
```

This code is in my customer class how do I get this information in my append class??

Comment: What does this have to do with [JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly something like this:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
// do some stuff with your customer object, including initiating the File and saving its name to a String field called name
Append append = new Append();
append.foo(customer.getName()); // passes the name of the file to the foo method of class Append
```

This assumes that you'll only want the name of the file in that one method (though you could save it to a field as part of method `foo()`). You'd need to implement a method `foo(String name)` in class Append.

Another option would be to pass it as a constructor of Append:

```
Append append = new Append(customer.getName());
append.foo();
```

For this, you'd need to implement a constructor `Append(String name)` in class Append.

Comment: +1 Append append = new Append(customer.getName());
append.foo();

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this depending on what exactly it is you are trying to do.

1. Give the Append class a member variable of the Customer class
2. Have the Append class constructor take a parameter that would refer to a Customer, such as a String of name or a Customer object as this is Java

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear to me, but here's a problems you might run into based on your description:

- What is getName() supposed to return, the name of the file, or the name of the person? If it's supposed to return the file name, then use getFileName() instead - it's clearer!

I don't really understand why you'd need an Append class. Personally, I'd handle appending additional info inside the Customer class. I'd do it so that every time a value is added or changed, the info is saved back into the file like:

```
class Customer {
    public void setForename(String forename) { 
        this.forename = forename;
        save();
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) { 
        this.surname = surname;
        save();
    }
    public void save() {
        // clear file
        // add new content
        String fileContents = "forename="+forname+"&surname="+surname;
        // save to file
    }
```

Maybe I'm not understanding your needs correctly though...

Comment: I agree.  The additional information if related to a customer should be stored as a property of the customer object.  This can be as simple as a String or more complex like an append class (append is not very descriptive though).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to DeadPassive's answer of associating the additional information with the Customer object:

The saving of the Customer data does not belong in the Customer Class.  The logic of persisting the data belongs in a seperate layer than the code that deals with manipulating the problem domain. A controller or service class seems like a more appropriate place to put the persistance logic.